# How can I declare '''vector<Point>''' for contours in OpenCV using C++/CLR environment?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, clr, contour

I'm importing my code (OpenCV native C++) to clr managed language for .Net environment.
I fixed all mismatches managed and unmanaged related functions (such as string conversions) except one problem.

When I use the `<vector<Point> > contours;` in form.h header file, I have two error:
   1)C2872 Point is ambiguous    in form.h 
   2)C3699 '&&': cannot use this indirection on type 'System::Drawing::Point'  in vector.h header file.

Using the vector for this line `vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;` is fine and it seems the problem is "point" mismatching with the CLR managed language.

How can I use the '''vector''' to define  "contours"  to "findContours"  function without errors.

Thank you for your mention.

```
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
vector<vector<Point> > contours0;
findContours(image2, contours0, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and my C++ OpenCV native code is fine on it, But I'm importing my code in CLR and now I have the problem.

Comment: Did you try to fully specify your type ? Like using `X::Y::Point` instead of `Point`. You seem to use `using namespace X`, try without

Comment: I have these line on the first of form.h code: ```using namespace System; using namespace std; using namespace cv;``` and some branch of namespace system::... .

Comment: Well try without. `Point is ambiguous` can be because of these lines.

Comment: You should avoid to use multiple `using namespace` instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Morterol and @ Fareanor. I removed STD and CV global namespace and I remain System and its branch namespace from/on the first of form.h code.
It works well.
The Solution was simple but it could be a big trouble. I'm really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I removed STD and CV global namespaces and I left System and its branch namespaces from the first of form.h code.
It works well.
The Solution was simple but it could be a big trouble.
I'm really grateful.